# Añadir un número concreto de EditText, determinado por el usuario de la aplicación

Tags: android, edittext

Estoy creando una aplicación en la que la primera Activity pregunta por el número de personas que van a participar.
En la siguiente Activity se procede a pedir el nombre de cada una de esas personas.

Teniendo en cuenta que ya tengo en el código Java en una variable esa cantidad de personas, ¿cómo podría añadir en esa segunda Activity tantos EditText (para escribir ahí los nombres de las personas) como número de personas han sido indicadas en la primera Activity?

Este es mi código Java de la primera Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText txtNumJugadores;
    private Button btnAceptar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Obtenemos una referencia a los controles de la interfaz
        txtNumJugadores = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNumJugadores);
        btnAceptar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAceptar);

        //Empleamos el evento click del botón
        btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Creamos el intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NombreJugadoresActivity.class);
                //Creamos la información a pasar entre actividades
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("numJugadores", Integer.parseInt(txtNumJugadores.getText().toString()));
                //Añadimos la información al intent
                intent.putExtras(b);
                //Iniciamos la nueva actividad
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

En la segunda activity, obtengo el número de personas introducidas por el usuario.

```
public class NombreJugadoresActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText txtNombreJugador;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nombre_jugadores);

        //Localizar los controles
        txtNombreJugador = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreJugador);
        //Recuperamos la información pasada en el intent
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        int numJugadores = bundle.getInt("numJugadores");
    }
}
```

Y mi problema es que en esta segunda Activity quiero introducir tantos EditText como número de personas van a participar (tantos EditText como indica la variable *numJugadores*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NombreJugadoresActivity` puede encargarse de generar dinámicamente tantos EditText como el valor de `numJugadores` que recibe de `MainActivity`

Eso lo puedes lograr mediante una sentencia `for` que cree un objeto `EditText` en cada iteración y lo agregue a tu layout.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nombre_jugadores);
    //Localizar los controles
    txtNombreJugador = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreJugador);
    //Recuperamos la información pasada en el intent
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    int numJugadores = bundle.getInt("numJugadores");
    for(int i = 0; i< numJugadores; i++){
         EditText editText= new EditText(this);
         editText.setId("editText"+i);
         edttext.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        layout.addView(editText); // 'layout' será tu LinearLayout/RelativeLayout/lo que sea que estes utilizando. Al principio del método deberas obtenerlo mediante findViewById
    }

}
```

[Referencia : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985825/generating-edit-text-programatically-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985825/generating-edit-text-programatically-in-android)

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero si me pudieras explicar que debo obtener exactamente mediante el _findViewById_ y cómo hacerlo te lo agradecería.

Comment: El layout que estas utilizando para esa activity, como un LinearLayout por ejemplo. Lo tienes definido como layout.activity_nombre_jugadores